# Cache key expiration event or callback in Python

Tags: python, caching

I am trying to find a way to receive invocation of a user function when a cache item has expired in **python**.

This functionality already exists in .NET as follow:

```
string test = "test1";
Cache.Insert("Key", 
    test, 
    dependancy, 
    DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(DateTime.Now), 
    System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, 
    CacheItemPriority.High, 
    new CacheItemRemovedCallback(CacheRemovedCallback));

public string CacheRemovedCallback(String key, object value, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemRemovedReason removedReason)
{
    //Do something here
    return  = "Cache Expired for : " + key;
}
```

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using any specific cache library or you are about to select one?

Comment: @Leon I don't have any choice at the moment. Anything that's is robust, production usable and has basic data caching features along with key expiration event.

Comment: @muntakim360, have you found any solution for that? I see the question was asked 3 years ago but still:)